# Does $ZFC^-$ plus $\mathcal{P}^\gamma$ have a countable $L_\alpha$ model if it has a countable model?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

Suppose $ZFC^-$ is $ZFC$ minus the power set axiom, and that, for $\gamma$ a countable ordinal,  $\mathcal{P}^\gamma$ is an axiom that allows less than $\gamma$ applications of the power set operation. Let S be $ZFC^-$ plus $\mathcal{P}^\gamma$. Is there a countable ordinal $\alpha$ so that $L_\alpha$ is a model of S if S has a countable model?

Comment: *(Ignoring the issue of precisely phrasing $\mathcal{P}^\gamma$)* Yes, as with your earlier question: take the Mostowski collapse of a large enough countable elementary submodel of $L_\kappa$, for $\kappa$ appropriate, and apply Condensation.

Comment: @NoahSchweber My understanding was that the appropriate $\kappa$ for your $L_\kappa$ was uncountable, to the level $\beth_\gamma$, and so $L_\kappa$ would be a standard model. But I do not ask whether there is a countable ordinal $\alpha$ so that $L\alpha$ is a model of S if S has a standard model.

Comment: Even taking $\gamma=1$ (so not changing $\mathsf{ZFC}$ at all), it's consistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}$ that $\mathsf{ZFC}$ has a countable model but no well-founded model, and so in particular no level of $L$ satisfying $\mathsf{ZFC}$. Does this answer your question?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I don't understand. Do you say that the fact that there are unfounded models of ZFC rules out the existence of well founded models of ZFC?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I would interpret $S$ with $\gamma=1$ as $S=S\cup\{\mathcal{P}(A)|A\in ZFC\}$

Comment: No, I am saying that it is *consistent* with $\mathsf{ZFC}$ that $\mathsf{ZFC}$ has illfounded models (hence ill-founded countable models by dLS) but no well-founded models of any cardinality.

Comment: "$S\cup\{\mathcal{P}(A)\vert A\in ZFC\}$" makes no sense whatsoever. What is the powerset of an axiom?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I identified $ZFC$ with the set of its theorems. The notation I use is common, e.g. in the metalogic of modal logic.

Comment: At any rate, your comment on ill founded models suggests the question: Is there a countable ordinal $\alpha$ so that $L_\alpha$ is a model of S if S has a countable well founded model?

Comment: @NoahSchweber ".. it's consistent with  that  has a countable model but no well-founded model, and so in particular no level of  satisfying . Does this answer your question?" Yes

Comment: @NoahSchweber A shorter answer is to say that S may only have non-standard models, which are not in $L$. So, the world may be as seen from the minimal transitive model of S.